# I already have a CUDA toolkit installed, why is conda installing CUDA again?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, conda, tensorflow2.0, cudnn

I have installed cuda version 11.2 and CUDNN version 8.1 in ubuntu

```
cnvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:08:53_PST_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
```

When I installed tensorflow-gpu in conda environment, it is again installing cuda and cudnn.

- Why is it happening.
- How to stop conda from installing cuda and cudnn again?
- Can I just use cuda and cudnn that I have already installed? If yes, how?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why is it happening?

Conda expects to manage any packages you install *and* all their dependencies. The intention is that you literally never have to install anything else by hand for any packages they distribute in their own channel. If a GPU accelerated package requires a CUDA runtime, conda will try to select and install a correctly versioned CUDA runtime for the version of the Python package it has selected for installation.

> 2. How to stop conda from installing cuda and cudnn again?

You probably can't, or at least can't without winding up with a non-functional Tensorflow installation. But see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61533291/681865) -- what conda installs is only the necessary, correctly versioned CUDA runtime components to make their GPU accelerated packages work. All they don't/can't install is a GPU driver for the hardware.

> 3. Can I just use cuda and cudnn that I have already installed?

You say you installed CUDA 11.2. If you look at the conda output, you can see that it wants to install a CUDA 10.2 runtime. As you are now [fully aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70692914/681865), versioning is critical to Tensorflow and a Tensorflow build requiring CUDA 10.2 won't work with CUDA 11.2. So even if you were to stop conda from performing the dependency installation, there is a version mismatch so it wouldn't work.

> 4. If yes, how?

See above.